# Single variable category scatter plot pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bokeh

Is It possible to plot single value as scatter plot? 
I can very well plot it in line by getting the ccdfs with markers but I want to know if any alternative is available?

Input:

Input 1

```
tweetcricscore 51 high active
```

Input 2

```
tweetcricscore 46 event based
tweetcricscore 12 event based
tweetcricscore 46 event based
```

Input 3

```
tweetcricscore 1 viewers 
tweetcricscore 178 viewers
```

Input 4

```
tweetcricscore 46 situational
tweetcricscore 23 situational
tweetcricscore 1 situational
tweetcricscore 8 situational
tweetcricscore 56 situational
```

I can very much write scatter plot code with `bokeh` and `pandas` using `x` and `y` values. But in case of single value ?

When all the inputs are merged as one input and are to be grouped by `col[3]`, values are `col[2]`.

**The code below is for data set with 2 variables**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import*
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Scatter, output_file, show

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', header = None)

df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']

scatter = Scatter( df, x='col2', y='col3', color='col4', marker='col4', title='plot', legend=True)

output_file('output.html', title='output')

show(scatter)
```

Sample Output

[image]

Comment: For scetterplot you have to say what do you want to have as x-axis and as y-axis. Alternatively you may have a `barplot` having category/etc. names as x-axis.

Comment: Yes it clear to have scatter plot x and y are needed.  But in this case I have univariate data as output with different categories.  Line and bar are very common.  I am trying to find a much better visualisation type.

Comment: @MaxU one more reason for not plotting bar charts is the inputs range to 1 to 1000s of values

Comment: how many different categories are you going to have? I'm __not__ asking  about values...

Comment: @MaxU As shown above three column with third column as category and 5 categories at max.

Comment: you can simply sum up your values for each category - would it be useful for you?

Comment: @MaxU I cannot sum up coz these are outputs from some kind of classification and these categories are the classes.  Can. Be written in one or independent output file.  some kind of final results and how we show them in better way is challenge here..

Comment: Perhaps a [swarmplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html)?

Comment: @mwaskom I am facing this issues with `swarmplot` data length is about 8k+ rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

look at [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/gallery.html#gallery) and [Seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/) galleries - it might help you to understand what kind of plot fits your needs

you may try violinplot like this:

```
sns.violinplot(x="category", y="val", data=df)
```

[image]

or HeatMaps:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import HeatMap, output_file, show

cats = ['active', 'based', 'viewers', 'situational']
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.randint(1,100, 1000), 'category': np.random.choice(cats, 1000)})

hm = HeatMap(df)
output_file('d:/temp/heatmap.html')
show(hm)
```

Comment: How about swarm plot?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a [boxplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) or [violinplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.violinplot). Alternatively if you don't like these and just want a vertical distribution of dots you could force a scatter to plot along a single x value. To do this you would need to create an array of a fixed value (say 1) that is the same length as the array you will be plotting:

```
ones = []
for range(len(data)):
    ones.append(1)

plt.scatter(ones,data)
plt.show()
```

That will give you something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Grr for the solution. it's not about not liking line or bar plot. Its just that they are too common and want to search if any more interesting visualisations are available out thr that I should know about.

Comment: one more reason for not plotting bar charts is the inputs range to 1 to 1000s of values

Comment: How about swarm plot?

Comment: Yea that's a good one. Documentation is [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153410/how-to-create-swarm-plot-with-matplotlib/36153957) has a good example of a swarmplot boxplot combo.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot index on x-axis and column value on y-axis

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))
sns.scatterplot(data=df['A'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something I use rather regularly is a "size plot" – a visualization similar to the one you're requesting where a single feature can be compared across groups. ***Here is an example using your data:***

[image: a size plot made using matplotlib]

**Here is the code to achieve this size plot:**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,5))

colors = ['blue','green','orange','pink']

yticks = {"ticks":[],"labels":[]}
xticks = {"ticks":[],"labels":[]}

agg_functions = ["mean","std","sum"]

# Set size plot
for i, (label, group_df) in enumerate(df.groupby('type', as_index=False)):

    # Set tick
    yticks["ticks"].append(i)
    yticks["labels"].append(label)

    agg_values = group_df["tweetcricscore"].aggregate(agg_functions)

    for ii, (agg_f, x) in enumerate(agg_values.iteritems()):
        ax.scatter(x=ii, y = i, label=agg_f, s=x, color=colors[i])


        # Add your x axis
        if ii not in xticks["ticks"]:
            xticks["ticks"].append(ii)
            xticks["labels"].append(agg_f)


# Set yticks:
ax.set_yticks(yticks["ticks"]) 
ax.set_yticklabels(yticks["labels"], fontsize=12)

ax.set_xticks(xticks["ticks"]) 
ax.set_xticklabels(xticks["labels"], fontsize=12)


plt.show()
```