# Add image annotations to boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, plot-annotations

I would like to add image annotations to a boxplot, akin to what they did with the bar chart in this post:
[How can I add images to bars in axes (matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971090/how-can-i-add-images-to-bars-in-axes-matplotlib)

My dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names = ['PersonA', 'PersonB', 'PersonC', 'PersonD','PersonE','PersonF']
regions = ['NorthEast','NorthWest','SouthEast','SouthWest']
dates = pd.date_range(start = '2021-05-28', end = '2021-08-23', freq = 'D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'runtime': np.repeat(dates, len(names))})
df['name'] = len(dates)*names
df['A'] = 40 + 20*np.random.random(len(df))
df['B'] = .1 * np.random.random(len(df))
df['C'] = 1 +.5 * np.random.random(len(df))
df['region'] = np.resize(regions,len(df))
```

I tried to use the AnnotationBbox method which worked great for my time-series, but I'm not entirely sure if it can be applied here.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
df.boxplot(column='A', by=['name'],ax=ax,showmeans=True, fontsize=8, grid=False)

for name in names:
  rslt_df = df[df['name']==name] 
  val = rslt_df['A'].values[0]
  xy = (0, val)

  fn = get_sample_data(f"{name}.png", asfileobj=False)
  arr_img = plt.imread(fn, format='png')
  imagebox = OffsetImage(arr_img, zoom=0.125)
  imagebox.image.axes = ax

  ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy,xybox=(15.,0),xycoords='data',boxcoords="offset points",pad=0,frameon=False)
  ax.add_artist(ab)
```

[image: PersonA.png]
[image: PersonB.png]
[image: PersonC.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The code in the OP if very similar to [Add image annotations to bar plots axis tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44246650/7758804), but needs to be modified because `boxplots` are slightly different the `barplots`.
- The main issue was `xy` didn't have the correct values.

  - The `xy` and `xybox` parameters can be adjusted to place the images anywhere.
- By default, `boxplot` positions the ticks at `range(1, n+1)`, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68958662/7758804)

  - Reset the tick positions with a 0 index: `positions=range(len(names))`
- `df` was created with `names = ['PersonA', 'PersonB', 'PersonC']` since only 3 images were provided.

```py
ax = df.boxplot(column='A', by=['name'], showmeans=True, fontsize=8, grid=False, positions=range(len(names)))
ax.set(xlabel=None, title=None)

# move the xtick labels
ax.set_xticks(range(len(names)))
ax.set_xticklabels(countries)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=30)

# use the ytick values to locate the image
y = ax.get_yticks()[1]

for i, (name, data) in enumerate(df.groupby('name')):

    xy = (i, y)

    fn = f"data/so_data/2021-08-28/{name}.png"  # path to file
    arr_img = plt.imread(fn, format='png')
    imagebox = OffsetImage(arr_img, zoom=0.125)
    imagebox.image.axes = ax

    ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy, xybox=(0, -30), xycoords='data', boxcoords="offset points", pad=0, frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
```

[image]

Comment: "By default, boxplot positions the ticks at range(1, n+1), so reset it with a 0 index positions=range(len(names))"

WOW. Yes, this helps SO MUCH.

Comment: @p3hndrx I didn’t know about the parameter until I made this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68958662/7758804) the other day

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the y-ticks don't always position themselves in a friendly manner, so I set a static Y-value (the x-axis). Creating a transform xycoords, allows placement directly below the x-axis, no matter the y-tick scale.

```
# BOX GRAPH PLOT
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='darkslategrey')
plt.style.use('dark_background')

ax = df.boxplot(column=str(c), by=['name'],ax=ax,showmeans=True, fontsize=8,grid=False,positions=range(len(top)))
ax.set(xlabel=None, title=None)


# move the xtick labels
ax.set_xticks(range(len(top)))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=20)

# use the ytick values to locate the image
y = ax.get_xticks()[0]


for i, (name, data) in enumerate(df.groupby('name')):
    xy = (i, y)

    fn = f"{imgsrc}/{name}.png"  # path to file
    arr_img = plt.imread(fn, format='png')
    imagebox = OffsetImage(arr_img, zoom=0.125)
    imagebox.image.axes = ax

    trans = ax.get_xaxis_transform()
    ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy, xybox=(0, -15), xycoords=trans,boxcoords="offset points", pad=0, frameon=False)
    
    ax.add_artist(ab)

    plt.show()
```