# Can I do jittered/scattered dot plots without overlaps with Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I would like to present individual data points (NMSE values for a number of experiments in, let's say, two categories) similar to a box plot, and I want to show all individual data points. Assuming the main direction of the data is upside-down, a jittered (or scattered) dot plot is a nice way to slightly move data points sideways to avoid overlapping dots. For a visualization of this idea, check [Google Image Search](https://www.google.de/search?tbm=isch&q=%22jittered%20dot%20plot%22) or [this article](https://www.dataplusscience.com/TableauJitter.html).

I have found and read [Adding a scatter of points to a boxplot using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779079/adding-a-scatter-of-points-to-a-boxplot-using-matplotlib), but these solution involve adding random noise irrespective of the data, so one has to fine tune parameters and maybe reiterate until one has a nice solution. And then you try to reproduce these a couple of months later ;)

So I would like an automated solution that creates figures such as the ones shown [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-dot-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization#rdoc). Are there solutions to do this with Matplotlib?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create swarm plot with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153410/how-to-create-swarm-plot-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a "swarmplot", which is nicely [implemented in seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_categorical.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="muted")

# Load the example iris dataset
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

# "Melt" the dataset to "long-form" or "tidy" representation
iris = pd.melt(iris, "species", var_name="measurement")

# Draw a categorical scatterplot to show each observation
sns.swarmplot(x="measurement", y="value", hue="species", data=iris)
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution. And for those slightly intimidated by the `DataFrame` format and `pd.melt`, rest assured: "[Input data can be passed in a variety of formats, including (...) Anything accepted by `plt.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html)." Awesome.